# The identify with cross product : how to understand?

Tags: cross-product, finite-element-method

The problem come from the notations in [Hansbo's paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/gamm.201490018/pdf) (page 197) and [his another paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782502005248). Given a domain $\Omega$, the function $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. $\Omega$ is divided into 2 subdomains $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ which are separated by the interface $\Gamma$. The restriction of $u$ on $\Omega_1$ is $u_1$ (i.e., $u|_{\Omega_1}=u_1$) and on $\Omega_2$ is $u_2$ (i.e., $u|_{\Omega_2}=u_2$). He consider the finite element space $V^h=V_1^h\times V^h_2$ where

$V_i^h=\{\phi_i\in H^1(\Omega_i):\phi_i|_{K_i}\text{ is linear },\phi_i|_{\partial \Omega_i}=0\}$.

After that, he constructs the basis functions $\psi$ for space $V^h$ by 2 basis functions $\psi_1,\psi_2$ of $V^h_1,V^h_2$. Then he identify $\psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2)=(\psi|_{\Omega_1},\psi|_{\Omega_2})$.

**My question:** How can we understand exactly the idea of "identify" in this case? Other words, $\psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2)\in V^h_1\times V^h_2$ whereas $\psi_{\Omega_i}=\psi_i$. For example, take $x\in \Omega_1$, $\psi(x)=\psi_1(x)$ because of the restriction of $\psi$ on $\Omega_1$. However, $\psi(x)$ must be $(\psi_1(x),\psi_2(x))$ because of the identify of $\psi$. It makes me confused!

Comment: Could you summarize the notation here?

Comment: @Travis: sorry, I don't understand your question clearly? Which notations in my question you don't understand?

Comment: The notation seems clear to me now, please disregard the comment.